# Multiple counts one request?

Tags: mongodb, count, database

Is there any way for me to return multiple counts in one request?

Rather then running `users.find({gender:"male"}).count();` and getting `231` then running `users.find({gender:"female"}).count();` getting `416` something that could return `{male:"231",female:"416"}`. I know map reduce can do this, is that my best bet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Groupby`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#_S_group) in `Aggregation` framework will do the trick

```
 db.users.aggregate({$group:{_id:'$gender',count:{$sum:1}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

RameshVel is correct. The `$group` command is probably what you're looking for.

For example, the following query:

`db.people.aggregate({$group: {_id: '$gender', total: { $sum : 1 }}})`

Will produce the following result:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": "m",
      "total": 49988
    },
    {
      "_id": "f",
      "total": 50012
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

You can read more about MongoDB's aggregation framework here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Hope that helps.